# Combined search query of openfda.generic_name and inactive ingredients only provides info for OTC products?

Tags: openfda

I think the title explains the question.  Im trying to run a query that pull specified legend drug name and specified inactive ingredient.  The results only seem to have an inactive ingredient property for OTC products and not rx drugs?

Comment: Hi there. Any chance we could see the query in question?

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be *entirely* the case; the following query shows there are Rx drugs with inactive ingredients listed:

[https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.product_type.exact:%22HUMAN%20PRESCRIPTION%20DRUG%22+AND+*exists*:inactive_ingredient](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.product_type.exact:%22HUMAN%20PRESCRIPTION%20DRUG%22%20AND%20_exists_:inactive_ingredient)

I agree the number of hits is somewhat small: **695**. This information, however, comes from the SPL files, which originate from within the FDA.